# Do do I make a bash script that runs in rc.local and issues the echo/read so it gets displayed in a currently open terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, echo

I'm using Linux 16.04 and what I'm trying to accomplish is to run a certain script that, when a terminal is opened and the program python is active, kills python and asks you questions and stores the answers.

The problem is that when it is run in rc.local it does stop python but does not forward the questions or echo messages to me. And that brings me to my question: Do do I make a bash script that runs in rc.local and issues the echo/read so it gets displayed in a currently open terminal?

Comment: So you want to "take over" the terminal, interrupt whatever is running there, ask the questions, read the answers and give control back to the original program?

Comment: More or less but my script already kills one of the things running there so, how should I go about doing what you said?

Comment: OK, you want to do this on the same terminal where the python was running. Wrapper script comes to mind. But then, why let user run python and then kill it?

Comment: You could say python being active is the trigger for everything and, to continue the script, you have to kill it.